# Is it possible to make an UILabel, UITextView, or similar that always resizes its height to fit its content in Interface Builder without truncating?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, uilabel

I've got a `xib` that I'm using for table cells (of variable heights, in a vertical UITableView), and each cell is populated with data that has an image and variable length text, but likely with different amounts of lines. I've tried wrapping them in an `horizontal UIStackView`, but I've found that there's no text view that resizes its container to fit variable multiple lines.

Both `UILabel` and `UITextView` truncate their contents seemingly arbitrarily in Interface Builder, while resizing the image's height makes the UIStackView container grow and shrink accordingly to wrap its contents.

**Is there any view or a way to add a custom view that dinamically resizes its height according to its text length, without truncating?**

Comment: Select `UILabel` and in attributes inspector just set `numberOfLines` to 0 and wrap mode to `word wrap`. If you have set constraints properly then it will always resize to fit its content. I'm not sure how it works in a stack view but inside a normal `UIView` it works fine.

Comment: At least in Interface Builder, it does not resize when changing the text in the properties sidebar, even when lines are 0 and `word wrap` is set.

Comment: It should even in interface builder. Probably some constraints aren't allowing it to resize properly as an inferred constraint has a lower priority than an explicitly defined constraint, try giving the `UILabel` a height of `>=` 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want :)

[image]

There are loads of tutorials on how to achieve it :) Anyway lemme explain steps here, hope it helps :)

**Tip:**

Make use of tableView's `estimatedRowHeight` and set it to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and let `UITableView` do the magic for u :)

**Step 1:**

Either create cell xib or create a prototype cell on UITableViewController. Whichever you feel comfortable with. Creating a cell xib, iOS expects you to register the xib with reusable identifier in `ViewDidLoad()` I am planning to avoid it hence creating a prototype cell in UITableViewController :) Lets provide it a reusable identifier :)

[image]

**Step 2:**

Drag UIImageView and UITextView and apply constraints as shown :)
This answer assumes your imageView height is fixed :) In case it is not tweak the answer a little :)

[image]

Now the imageView has H:|-(8)-[ImageView]-(8)-| and V: |-(8)-[ImageView]
and finally height constraint of 100 :)

Now add TextView below it :)

[image]

TextView has no height constraints :) It just has top, bottom left and right constraints :)

**Step 3:**

[image]

Now select textView, and carefully uncheck Scrolling enabled, shows horizontal and vertical indicator :)

**Step 4:**

In viewDidLoad of your tableViewController or ur viewController write :)

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
```

**Step 5 :**

Now sit back, relax, run the code, get excited and please comeback and accept answer :)

**EDIT**

In case wondering what else I might have written in UITableViewController :) Just tableView data source methods `numberOfSections`,`numberOfRowsInSection`,`cellForRowAt` thats all. Nothing else required :)